# mongoexport to csv via cron

Tags: mongodb, cron, mongoexport

issues dumping data from mongodb to csv via crontab.

my mongoexport command, which works via commandline

```
mongoexport -h xx.xx.xx.xx -d mqtt -c message -o mqtttest.csv --csv -f 
message,timestamp
```

the shell script to execute above command /csv/test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
mongoexport -h xx.xx.xx.xx -d mqtt -c message -o mqtttest.csv --type=csv -f 
message,timestamp
```

cron job

```
30 * * * * ./csv/test.sh
```

my mqtttest.csv file is not being made and not sure why

thoughts? thank you

Comment: `/csv/test.sh` and `./csv/test` are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: I tried /csv/test as well and no luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined the directory from where to run your `test.sh` or define the complete absolute path for the `test.sh` file in crontab.

To define the directory, configure your cron as:

```
30 * * * * cd /path/to/dir && ./csv/test.sh
```

Also, make sure that your `test.sh` file has  execution rights.

`chmod +x test.sh` from the csv directory

Comment: dir path to output file or test.sh file? test.sh is located in ~/csv/ folder @agarwalankur85

Comment: @lostislandguy dir path to  your test.sh file till your /csv folder. Example: `cd /home/app/job && ./csv/test.sh` if you test.sh file is in `/home/app/job/csv/test.sh` dir

Comment: its in my root/csv folder. should it be in /var/www/html/somefolder ?@agarwalankur85

Comment: Could you `cd` to csv folder and run `pwd` or `cwd` to get the absolute path of the csv folder and paste it here? @lostislandguy

Comment: /root/csv   @agarwalankur85

Comment: Your crontab entry should be `30 * * * * cd /root &amp;&amp; ./csv/test.sh` Make sure you have set right permissions to your test.sh file. Check edit in the answer. @lostislandguy

Comment: i've set it to run @ 1min for testing, and no go. test.sh has the correct permissions. so looks like: 1 * * * * cd /root &amp;&amp; ./csv/test.sh @agarwalankur85

Comment: i have no /var/log/cron dir.. ** DISREGARD **  grep CRON /var/log/syslog @agarwalankur85

Comment: Are you able to run the test.sh file directly from command line. `/root/csv/test.sh`? @lostislandguy

Comment: cron output.... `Feb 19 15:05:01 localhost CRON[22356]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 19 15:15:01 localhost CRON[22375]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Feb 19 15:17:01 localhost CRON[22378]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`

Comment: yes.. `root@localhost:~# /root/csv/test.sh
2018-02-19T15:24:10.585+0000    connected to: xx.xx.xx.xx
2018-02-19T15:24:10.587+0000    exported 253 records`